# How to show a new Stage from my own thread in JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have to run some task in another thread and when some condition has been met in that threads `run()` method I must display a pop-up window with a a picture inside it, however trying to do that causes an Exception that tells me that I can't create any stages outside the main UI thread, **now is there a way to go around this, can I somehow access the UI thread from my custom thread and make it show the stage?** (Note: because of the nature of the application, I must use a custom thread for checking the condition, because there is like 8 different threads checking the same condition at the same time.)

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap your actions with `Platform.runLater(...)`

```
new Thread(() -> {
      Platform.runLater(() -> { 

          /* Your code goes here */

      });   
}).start();
```

Comment: (Obviously, only the UI code is wrapped in the `Platform.runLater(...)`, not the entire content of the thread's runnable.)