# JavaFX- new Stage in a task

Tags: java, javafx

I want to open a new window from the task but for some reason after line `Stage stage = new Stage` the code stops executing, but there is no error.

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {

        @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            System.out.println("Print");
            stage.setTitle("My New Stage Title");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
            stage.show();
            return null;
        }
    };
```

It never prints out the message 'Print'.

Comment: Don't do this in the background.

Comment: If you must attempt it, try putting all the code in `Platform.runlater();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45414133/how-to-show-a-new-stage-from-my-own-thread-in-javafx

Comment: Platform helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to Question

The reason your `Task` is failing is because you are creating a `Stage` on a thread other than the JavaFX Application Thread. The Javadoc of `Stage` states:

> Stage objects must be constructed and modified on the JavaFX Application Thread.

This means when you attempt to create a `Stage` on the background thread that the `Task` is running on it will result in an `IllegalStateException` with a message telling you that you aren't on the JavaFX Application Thread. To solve this issue wrap all code that creates and/or modifies a `Stage` in a `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` call.

*Side Note:* It would probably be better to not create the `Stage` in the `Task` at all. Rather, in your case, simply return the result of `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` and create the `Stage` when handling the success of the `Task`.

```
Task<Parent> task = new Task<Parent>() {
    @Override
    protected Parent call() throws Exception {
        return FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));
    }
};

task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
    Parent root = task.getValue();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
};
```

#### Why No Error Shown?

You say there is no error but you also don't show any code that would display an error if one does occurr. When a `Task` fails it sets the cause of failure in the [`exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#exceptionProperty) property. To handle the case when a `Task` fails you can:

- Listen to the `exception` property
- Add an `EventHandler` to handle a `WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_FAILED` event and query the `exception` property

  - Either using `task.setOnFailed(EventHandler)` or `task.addEventXXX(EventType, EventHandler)` where `XXX` is either `Filter` or `Handler`
- Override the `protected void failed()` method in your `Task` implementation and query the `exception` property

  - The `failed()` method will always be called on the JavaFX Application Thread
- Catch and handle the exception in the `call()` method before re-throwing it
- Possibly other ways I'm not currently thinking of

Answer (score 0):

You need an Executor to start the thread

```
Executor exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(runnable -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t;
});

exec.execute(task);
```

Comment: Didn't work. Previously I run the task by 'task.run();'. The same effect for both.

Comment: To get the error you have to use, task.setOnFailed(e -> {task.getException().printStackTrace();});

Comment: And I think the error is going to be in , FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml"));, you cannot use static functions inside threads

Comment: Ok so the error is "Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4" for the line "Stage stage = new Stage()"

Comment: Ok I solved it. Instead of task I used "Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
// ...
});".

Comment: @GrzegorzBrzęczyszczykiewicz how did you did it please ? using the runLater