# Stage.close() doesn't work javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a main window and when I press a button on it, another window will open.
After a certain amount of time, this window should close. Because it extends `stage` I use `super.close`, but it doesn't work. What can I do? Can it be caused because I close it inside a service task?

```
public Game(int width, int height, int time) {
    this.width = width - 15;
    this.height = height - 15;
    this.time = time;

    this.layout = generateLayout();
    this.scene = new Scene(this.layout, this.width, this.height);

    super.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    super.setScene(scene);
    super.setResizable(false);
    super.setTitle(TITLE);

    this.cicle.reset();
    this.cicle.start();

    super.showAndWait();
}
```

and inside the `cicle` I call `close()`

It's a bit confused, but this is the `cicle` service task:

```
Service<Void> cicle = new Service<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            volatile boolean waiting = false;

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                Timer.start();
                while (Timer.update() / 1000 < time) {
                    System.out.println(Timer.update())
                }
                close();
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are attempting to close the [`Stage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close()) from a thread *other* than the JavaFX Application Thread. Looking at the documentation of `Stage` you'll see:

> Stage objects must be constructed and modified on the JavaFX
>   Application Thread.
>
> The JavaFX Application Thread is created as part of the startup
>   process for the JavaFX runtime. See the Application class and the
>   Platform.startup(Runnable) method for more information.

Yet a `Service`, when started, will execute its `Task` on a *background* thread. Specifically, the `call()` method of the `Task` is executed on said background thread. I just tested trying to close a `Stage` on a background thread to see what happens (whether or not an exception would be thrown). The result was an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-3`.

The reason you aren't seeing this is you aren't observing the `Service` for failure. You can look at [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736180/6395627) to see ways to watch for failure. The answer specifically talks about `Task` but the same behavior is present in `Service`.

What you need to do to make your code work is to make sure that `close()` is called on the JavaFX Application Thread. The easiest way to do this would be to wrap `close()` in a [`Platform.runLater(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) call.

```
Service<Void> cicle = new Service<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            volatile boolean waiting = false;

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                Timer.start();
                while (Timer.update() / 1000 < time) {
                    System.out.println(Timer.update())
                }
                Platform.runLater(() -> close()); // wrapped in Platform#runLater
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

You could also override [`Service.succeeded()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html#succeeded()) which will always be called on the JavaFX Application Thread (but only if the `Service` succeeds). In this case, you'd remove the call to `close()` from the `call()` method.

```
Service<Void> cicle = new Service<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            volatile boolean waiting = false;

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                Timer.start();
                while (Timer.update() / 1000 < time) {
                    System.out.println(Timer.update())
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        close();
    }

};
```

There are other ways as well: listening to the `state` property, using `setOnSucceeded(EventHandler)`, etc...